# Change Image from a ListAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I want to call a image from the res/drawable folder utilizing a ListAdapter

As of now, I can only retrieve and display the information as text.

My adapter is the following

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            ListagemHospitaisActivity.this, ListaHospitais,
                            R.layout.item_hospital, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                            TAG_NOME, TAG_LOTACAO},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.nome, R.id.lotacao });

                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                }
            });
```

The TAG_LOTACAO returns the exact name of the image I want to show.

The ImageView I want to alter is this

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imglotacao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/l_9_1"
        />
```

As I tried the method below I got a few problems.

```
private List<Hospitais> ListaHospitais; // or what type this list is
```

Do you refer to the ListaHospitais?

Other than that, The `<Hospitais>` gives out an error, and says to create Class. What am I doing wrong?

The `listData` is giving out an error as well, asking to create Local Variable

And here it is also showing a error as it cannot resolve method.

```
Hospitais item = (Hospitais) ListaHospitais.get(position);
holder.pid.setText(item.getPid());
holder.nome.setText(item.getNome());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Show an image in ListView based on info received from server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694564/how-to-show-an-image-in-listview-based-on-info-received-from-server)

Comment: Sorry, was supposed to delete the other one. I think this one is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your own custom adapter, something like this:

```
public class HospitaisAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Hospitais> ListaHospitais; // or what type this list is
    private Context context;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public HospitaisAdapter (Context context, List<Hospitais> ListaHospitais) {
        this.ListaHospitais= ListaHospitais;
        this.context=context;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ListaHospitais.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return ListaHospitais.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
         /*the row layout should be the layout for a row from your listview,
        containing your  imageView and nome as well as pid data.
        I will suppose pid and nome are Strings and are  displayed in a TextView */

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.pid= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pid);
            holder.nome= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nome);
            holder.image= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imglotacao);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Hospitais item = (Hospitais) ListaHospitais.get(position);

        holder.pid.setText(item.getPid());
        holder.nome.setText(item.getNome());

        holder.image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_name));


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView pid;
        TextView nome;
        ImageView image;

    }
}
```

And than use your adapter something like this:

```
listView.setAdapter(new HospitaisAdapter(this,ListaHospitais));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @HaneloreIanoseck ... I will try this an I will let you know.

Comment: I tried your solution and got some error. I have edited my question with the problems so it could be better formatted.

Comment: You should replace listData with ListaHospitais. I edited my answer. As for the list ListaHospitais I just assumed the type is a List<Hospitais> for this list. Of course if the type Hospitais does not exist it will say that you need to  create this class. You need to replace the type of ListaHospitais with the type you are using in your initial code.